# How to removed deleted apps in macOS' notification center?

Tags: notifications

[image]
As shown in this screenshot Bit Slicer, Adobe Desktop Service, Dropbox, and Creative Cloud have been removed but they remained in the notification center. Is it possible to remove them?

Comment: I have this problem with an app on macOS Monterey. I have uninstalled the app per the vendor's instructions (and also with CleanMyMac), but the problem persists. I have seen this question asked many times on the net, but I have never seen a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe CC has an uninstaller at `/Applications/Utilities/Adobe Creative Cloud/Utils/` which should tidy up many other things too, not just that panel.

For the other apps, check if they have their own uninstallers, which in some cases is inside the app itself so you may need to reinstall to uninstall.

Failing that, [CleanMyMac](https://macpaw.com/cleanmymac) can scour drives for left-over traces of uninstalled apps & both CleanMyMac & [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/) can scour for traces at the point of uninstall, though not afterwards.
I have no affiliation to either app or manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks. How does notification center aggregate apps showing in its panel?

Comment: Presumably, the app asks for permission at install or first run.